# std::vector::shrink_to_fit() does not check allocator equality

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector, allocator

I have my own stack allocator which works with the test cases I have except with `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()`

`shrink_to_fit()` tries to deallocate memory with a different stateful allocator than the memory was originally allocated from.

My understanding is that a container must check allocators for equality before memory allocated from one allocator is deallocated trough a different one. Am I wrong?

Quote from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator

> `a1 == a2` returns true only if the storage allocated by the allocator a1 can be
>   deallocated through a2. Establishes reflexive, symmetric, and
>   transitive relationship. Does not throw exceptions.

In my example, the equality check operators are not even called.

I am using g++ 5.4.0. A full code example can be found here:
https://onlinegdb.com/ryG9W5sx4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copies of an allocator must compare equal. Yours don't.

(It follows that even a stateful allocator cannot have embedded storage.)